# Largest hard disk you can install on a PS3?

Tags: ps3, hard-drive

My current PS3 HDD (1TB) is near capacity thanks to PS Plus IGC and several sales over the years. What's the largest capacity hard disk I can buy that will work with a PS3? I know there are certain restrictions as far as the height and width of the drive. On my PS4, I bought a 2TB hard disk and installed it successfully. I'd like to upgrade to the same HDD I installed on my PS4, but Googling and reading some forum posts; it seems the PS3 can't handle more then 1TB; though I have some read some reports of success with 1.5TB drives. Anybody have experience with installing a 1TB+ hdd on there PS3? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

> **Theoretically it is possible. In reality, it might be very difficult.**

It does not matter how much data your HDD can store. Your PS3 can technically support a 10 terabyte hard drive, but under some certain restrictions, it's not really possible.

You can't let the Hard Drive have any more than 9.5mm, or else it won't work. I have never seen a 1+ terabyte Hard Drive that would do the job, but it may be possible.

[Source](http://www.ign.com/boards/threads/ps3-hard-drive-upgrade-1tb.250128320/)

Comment: it just takes a 2.5 hdd, a laptop hdd.....the standard size